# Do we have any saxon specific Transformer class?

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

My Transformation code snippet is below:

```
EnterpriseConfiguration config = new EnterpriseConfiguration();
StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(sourceMsg));
EnterpriseTransformerFactory factory = new EnterpriseTransformerFactory();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xsltPath)));
System.out.println("config.isLicenseFound() " + config.isLicenseFound());
transformer.transform(xmlInput,xmlOutput);
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
System.out.println("OUTPUT :::-> " + xmlOutput.getWriter().toString());
```

Where I am using `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` class, I would like to know is there any tranformer which is specific to Saxon? If yes could suggest me any, Thanks in advance.

Here is the code which i am trying to achieve the functionality:

```
static HashMap<String, String> mapValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
public static HashMap<String, String> getMapValues() {
        return mapValues;
    }

    public static void setMapValues(HashMap<String, String> mapValues) {
        DecomposeXsl.mapValues = mapValues;
    }

public String transformXsl() throws IOException, SaxonApiException
    {
        mapValues.put("John", "Jbl");
        processor = new Processor(false);  
        xsltCompiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
        XPathCompiler xpathCompiler = new Processor(false).newXPathCompiler();
        String pageFragment = null;

        StreamSource xslStreamSource = new StreamSource(new File(xsltPath));

          XsltExecutable xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.compile(xslStreamSource); 
          xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.compile(xslStreamSource); 
          pageXmlTransformer = xsltExecutable.load();
          XsltTransformer transformer = null;

          transformer = pageXmlTransformer;
          String inputStr = null;
          //StringReader inputStrReader = new StringReader(inputStr); 
          StreamSource xmlDoc = new StreamSource(new File(sourcePath)); 
          Serializer serializer = new Serializer(); 
          serializer.setOutputWriter(new StringWriter()); 
          serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.SAXON_STYLESHEET_VERSION, "2.0"); 
          serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml"); 
          serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.MEDIA_TYPE, "text/html"); 
          serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "no"); 
          serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes"); 
          serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.ENCODING, "utf-8"); 
          transformer.setSource(xmlDoc);   
          transformer.setDestination(serializer); 
          transformer.transform();  
          pageFragment = serializer.getOutputDestination().toString();
          System.out.println("pageFragment "+pageFragment);
        return pageFragment;

    }
```

Exception i am getting is:

```
XTDE1425: Cannot find a matching 2-argument function named {java:java.util.Map}get().
  Reflexive calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE
  in built-in template rule
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Cannot find a matching 2-argument function named {java:java.util.Map}get(). Reflexive calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE
```

Here is my xsl code:

```
<xsl:param name="valMap" as="java:java.util.Map" required="no" select="controller:getMapValues()"/>

<newTag><xsl:value-of select="map:get($valMap, 'John')"/></newTag>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to answer if you told us why you need to know.

The literal answer to your question is yes, there is a Saxon-specific class that implements the JAXP Transformer interface. You can find out what it is by displaying the value of `transformer.getClass().getName()`. But you don't normally need to know what the class name is unless you want to achieve some special effect.

In the above code, creating an `EnterpriseConfiguration` is redundant, because you get one anyway when you create an `EnterpriseTransformerFactory`. It would be more sensible to call `getConfiguration()` on the factory. If you have two different Configuration objects around, you're probably going to get confused when you set properties on one of them and it has no effect.

And one other comment on your code: there's no point setting output properties AFTER doing the transformation: it's too late by then.

Comment: First of all thanks for your assistance, I have corrected the suggestions above, however i am still open with my question, actually i do not want to use Java transformation interface like Transformer . Instead any saxon specific like we have XSLTTransformer.

Comment: I have tried using it and the actual purpose is to call java method in xslt, The issue which i am facing is, whenever i try to do so with XSLTTransformer i am getting below execption:

Comment: Cannot find a matching 2-argument function named {java:java.util.Map}get(). Reflexive calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE

Comment: Even though i am using Saxon EE and i am getting config.isLicenseFound() as true, but still not able to trace from where it is refering Saxon HE.

Comment: When i am using javax.xml.transform.Transformer i am not getting any exception for the same.

Comment: Is there any way where i can make it stop reffering Saxon HE and use Saxon EE instead?

Comment: So my understanding is that when you use the s9api interface (i.e. when you use completely different code from the code in your question), you are not getting access to Saxon-EE functionality. That's probably because your s9api code is wrong. The most common mistake is when you call `new Processor()` the argument should be `true`. But problem solving is a lot easier if you tell us what code you are executing and exactly how it is failing.

Comment: Yes i have made the new Processor() as  true and am able to execute it without exception now, but i am getting <newTag> as empty. Any suggestions.

Comment: It was my bad, i was passing wrong class in the namespace. Its working fine for me. Thanks for the suggestion Michael.